# Why does the refrence not work correctly?

Tags: rest, api, python-3.4

I'm very new to Python, the whole API thing and Stack Overflow.
I wanted to connect to the Bricklink rest API and with a library, that I found on github.
Now the problem is, that the library has a class a that gets an instance in antoher class and if I run the code, class c wants to use the get function from class a by going through class b (I really don't know if this made any sense to you guys, sorry!)
I'll provide some code for better comprehension.
(Here is the link to the Bricklink library: https://github.com/robbietjuh/py-bricklink)

I tried to put the self.client in brackets in hope, that it then gets a higher priority, but it didn't work.. 
I searched for anything similar, but it was always too hard to understand or not helping.

```
class Method:       # this is class b
    client = None

    def __init__(self, client):
        self.client = client


class Orders(Method):      # this is class c
    URL_ORDER_LIST = 'orders'
    URL_ORDER_DETAILS = 'orders/{order_id}'
    URL_ORDER_ITEMS = 'orders/{order_id}/items'
    URL_ORDER_MESSAGES = 'orders/{order_id}/messages'
    URL_ORDER_FEEDBACK = 'orders/{order_id}/feedback'
    URL_ORDER_UPDATE = 'orders/{order_id}'
    URL_ORDER_UPDATE_STATUS = 'orders/{order_id}/status'
    URL_ORDER_UPDATE_PAYMENT_STATUS = 'orders/{order_id}/status'

    def getOrders(self, direction='in', status='', filed=False):
        params = {
            'direction':    direction,
            'status':       status,
            'filed':        filed,
            }
        return self.client.get(self.URL_ORDER_LIST, params)
```

## the code below is in another file

```
class ApiClient:     # this is class a
    def __init__(self, consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret):
        self.service = OAuth1Service(name='bricklink',
                                 consumer_key=consumer_key,
                                 consumer_secret=consumer_secret, base_url='https://api.bricklink.com/api/store/v1/')

        self.session = self.service.get_session((access_token, access_token_secret))

        self.orders = Orders(self)

    def request(self, method, url, params):
        if method in ('POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'):
            response = self.session.request(method, url, True, '', data=json.dumps(params), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}).json()
        else:
            response = self.session.request(method, url, True, '', params=params).json()
        return self.processResponse(response, method, url, params)

    def get(self, url, params={}):     # here is the get function, that is needed to be accessed
        return self.request('GET', url, params)


test = ApiClient('consumer_key', 'consumer_secret', 'access_token', 'access_token_secret')
print(test)
meth = a.Method(test)
order = a.Orders(meth)
order.getOrders(direction='in', status='', filed=False)
```

The Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Python Projects/Neuer Ordner/py-bricklink-master/bricklink/api.py", line 96, in <module>
        order.getOrders(direction='in', status='', filed=False)
    File "D:\Python Projects\Neuer Ordner\py-bricklink-master\bricklink\a.py", line 36, in getOrders
        return self.client.get(self.URL_ORDER_LIST, params)
AttributeError: 'Method' object has no attribute 'get'
```

So it should give me a list with the order_ids and many more, but if I run it, I get only the response "'Method' object has no attribute 'get'" and there are Errors in the lines, where I call the function "getOrders(...)" and in "return self.client.get(self.URL_ORDER_LIST, params)", where the function getOrders(...) returns the values.

Comment: If you got an exception/error, post the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I did so in the last part of my post.
But I will edit it in now

Comment: You are not showing the code that is creating the exception (i.e. `order.getOrders(...)`. How is `order` being created, etc. need more context.

Comment: Ohh sorry. now it is in there. on the last lines in the second code part.

Comment: Not sure why you are creating `a.Method` this is a baseclass of `a.Order` and is created automatically when you create an `a.Order` - `order = a.Orders(test)` would be the correct construction of an order.

Comment: Dude. Thanke you very much. I thought it would have to be way more complicated, but it was easier than I thought xp Thank you